# Is there a java library for function programming?

Tags: java, functional-programming

Has anybody written a library in java that provides mapping functions (such as mapcar from lisp).

I saw this [post](http://programmaticallyspeaking.blogspot.com/2008/06/lisps-mapcar-for-java-onall-collect.html) and few others (such as this one [this one](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=809652)), but sadly nothing that I could consider mainstream and/or usable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few. They are usually described as something like "functional programming in Java" libraries rather than by reference to LISP.

At my company, the functional programming druids settled on [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/) as their preferred library, although there is a significant and vocal minority who prefer the functional-esque provisions in [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Guava is a very mainstream and popular library; it's firmly in the "nobody got fired for using" category. FJ may be less well known, but we're using it pretty happily. We've even [forked it](https://github.com/youdevise/functionaljava) so we can help improve it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be looking forward to Java 8, then! It will have Project Lambda included, which has a much, much nicer syntax for closure-like anonymous classes.<sup>†</sup> Example:

```
Iterable<String> strs = ...
Iterable<String> downCased = strs.map(s -> s.toLowerCase());
```

*Any* interface with one method (or abstract class with one abstract method) can use this syntax, including Guava's `Function` and `Predicate` (though Java 8 has its own `Mapper` and `Predicate` interfaces, so these are usable out of the box). In this case `Iterable.map` is a new extension method that takes a new interface type called `Mapper`.

If you'd like more examples of Java 8 lambdas, just ask!

† All the usual restrictions of anonymous classes still apply, including that local free variables must be "effectively final". This means you don't have to explicitly tag the variable as `final`, but you're still not allowed to alter the value.

Comment: A minor point: lambda expressions will be convertible to instances of any type with a single abstract method, which means interfaces with one method, but also abstract classes with one abstract method. This is handy because Functional Java's [F](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/F.html) is an abstract class rather than an interface.

Comment: @TomAnderson: Excellent, thanks for the clarification! I'll edit the post accordingly.